# CardViews, no se muestran las imagenes

Tags: android

Saludos,

Mi problema es que no se muestran las imagenes que tengo en CardViews hasta que no haga un scroll, estoy usando la libreria Picasso.

¿Saben como puedo solucionar esto, para que al abrir la aplicacion, estas se muestre?

De antemano, muchas gracias.

```html
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private List<Unidades> unidad;
    private int layout;
    private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<Unidades> unidad, int layout, OnItemClickListener listener)
    {
        this.unidad = unidad;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.itemClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);

        context = parent.getContext();

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(unidad.get(position), itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return unidad.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textViewTitulo;
        TextView textViewDes;
        ImageView imageViewUnidad;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
     
            imageViewUnidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUnidad);
            textViewTitulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitulo);
            textViewDes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDes);
        }

        void bind(final Unidades unidad, final OnItemClickListener listener)
        {
            Picasso.with(context).load(unidad.getImg()).fit().into(imageViewUnidad);
            textViewTitulo.setText(unidad.getTitulo());
            textViewDes.setText(unidad.getDescrip());

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(unidad, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener
    {
        void onItemClick(Unidades unidades, int position);
    }
}
```

```html
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        unidad = this.getAllUnidades();

        componentes();
        configuration();
    }

    private void componentes()
    {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(unidad, R.layout.recycler_view_item, new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Unidades unidad, int position) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void configuration()
    {
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

[image: Primeros elementos al abrir la aplicacion]

[Deslizando hacia arriba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE3bT.png)

Comment: Public el codigo de como cargas las imagenes. Asi con imagenes no sera posible ayudarte.

Comment: Si, disculpa, es la primera vez que hago una pregunta aquí :)

Comment: Leningi, bienvenido al sitio, te recomiendo leas [ask] para conocer como realizar correctamente una pregunta, trata de agregar siempre código, y ser especifico, en este caso te recomendaría también agregar el layout recycler_view_item.xml. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio, bienvenido y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es un bug de Picasso, intenta ponerle un CallBack,

```
Picasso.with(context).load(unidad.getImg()).fit().into(imageViewUnidad, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, pero el metodo .reuse() me dice que no existe.

Comment: como te fue? ya actualicé el código

Comment: Lo implemente, sin embargo no pude resolver el problema. Pues no supe que iba dentro del onSucess(). Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Elimina el método `fit()` en la llamada:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(unidad.getImg()).into(imageViewUnidad);
```

Ya que este método trata de cambiar el tamaño de la imagen para que encaje exactamente en los limites del contenedor **pero `fit()` puede dar como resultado la ejecución retrasada de la solicitud!**